# IEnumerable Vs Rx Observable for a twitter API call

Tags: rabbitmq, system.reactive

I have a `ASP.NET WebAPI` that has to interact with a `Twitter API` and then log those tweets to `RabbitMQ` which later be picked up by another consumer of `RabbitMQ`. There will be between 500 to 1000 tweets expected to be pulled from Tweeter.

The approach that I'm planning to take is read all the 1000 tweets from Tweeter via [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) in-memory and then iterate using [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx), and then send a message to the RabbitMQ.

Will I get any benefit if I use [Rx Observable](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) in the place of `IEnumerable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you gain anything here by adopting Rx. If the feed was a push sequence and you wanted to compose that with other notifications (events/timers/feeds) then Rx may pay its way.